# How use asyncio with pyqt6?

Tags: python, pyqt, python-asyncio, pyqt6

qasync doesn't support pyqt6 yet and I'm trying to run discord.py in the same loop as pyqt but so far I'm not doing the best. I've tried multiprocess, multithread, and even running synchronous code from non-synchronous code but I either end up with blocking code that makes the pyqt program non responsive or it just outright doesn't work. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you use PyQt5 or PySide2 or PySide6 until qasync supports PyQt6?

Comment: before I realized I would need it I created my program with pyqt6, And porting it to pyqt5 has been a little rough. I'd need to recreate my program which wouldn't be ideal :/

Comment: @Lino right now PyQt6 has little differences from 5, and unless you're using specific new features added in Qt6 the only big difference is the usage of Enums. Also, AFAIK, if you use a recent version of PySide2, the problem doesn't present at all, since it already supports that naming pattern. For [very] future reference, always check for supported features when dealing with major versions that are pretty new: Qt6 has been released less than 9 months ago (which is not a lot for a *huge* toolkit like Qt is), and many features of Qt5 have been temporarily removed until they're considered mature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>qasync does not currently support PyQt6 but I have created a [PR](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync/pull/53) that implements it.</del>

<del>At the moment you can install my version of qasync using the following command:</del>

```
pip install git+https://github.com/eyllanesc/qasync.git@PyQt6
```

<del>Probably in future releases my PR will be accepted so there will already be support for PyQt6</del>

They already accepted my PR so you can already install the latest version of qasync that has support for PyQt6.

Answer (score 1):

```py
os.environ.setdefault("QT_API", "PyQt6")
from asyncqt import QEventLoop
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?